# Running Commands on Remote Linux Server Using SSH

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am writing a Bash Script wherein I need to run some set of commands on a remote Linux server from my local computer using SSH. I want the results to be displayed on the terminal screen or dump the results in a file on my local system.

How can achieve this? Is the following syntax correct?

```
\#!/bin/bash
.
.
.
.

ssh <user>@<remote_host> 'COMMAND >> /path/to/file ; scp /path/to/file <user>@<local_host>:<location>; exit'
.
.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The backslash before `#!` is certainly not correct. These two characters need to be the very first two bytes in the file in order for them to do anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the results display on the terminal screen:

```
ssh <user>@<remote_host> COMMAND
```

To have the results saved to a file:

```
ssh <user>@<remote_host> COMMAND > FILE
```

To have the results both displayed on the terminal screen and saved to a file:

```
ssh <user>@<remote_host> COMMAND | tee FILE
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you for the reply.

First command will display the results on terminal screen of remote host. I want it to be displayed on the terminal screen of local machine.

Comment: Since the ssh session is running in the terminal of your local machine, text that is displayed on the remote machine is also displayed on the local machine. I don't believe I understand exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not intervene, `stdout` will normally appear on the local terminal.  It can be saved to a local file as follow:

```
ssh <user>@<remote_host> COMMAND >my_local_file
```